# Error in R : not-yet-implemented method for <data.frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>

Tags: r, glmnet

I am working on a problem, but get an error like this:

```
Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
not-yet-implemented method for <data.frame> %*% <dgCMatrix>
```

Here are my code:

```
X.A = model.matrix(College.lm.A)[,-1]
# 
library(glmnet)
# # obtain the optimal lambda by cross-validation
lambda_1se = cv.glmnet(X.A, set.A$Apps)$lambda.1se
# 
# # refit glmnet using the chosen lambda
lasso.A.CV = glmnet(X.A, set.A$Apps, lambda = lambda_1se)
coef(lasso.A.CV)
# 
# # compare
coef_comp = cbind(OLS = coef(College.lm.A),
                  Ridge.CV = as.numeric(coef(lasso.A.CV)))
coef_comp
# 
# # get the model.matrix of the set B
X.b = model.matrix(lm(Apps ~., data=set.B))[,-1]
# 
# # calculate the mse.
#(set.B$Apps - predict(College.lm.A, set.B))
mse.lasso.cv = mean((set.B$Apps - predict(lasso.A.CV, set.B)^2))
data.frame(mse.ols, mse.lasso.cv)
```

How should I fixed this problem?

I tried to add model.matrix, and change the second last line to
`mse.lasso.cv = mean((set.B$Apps - predict(model.matrix(lasso.A.CV), set.B)^2))`
Then it also gave me an error as `"Error in terms.default(object) : no terms component nor attribute"`

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is meant for the lasso model object, the second argument, you should pass a matrix, also you don't need to refit the results of cv.glmnet, you can predict by calling s="lambda.1se" :

```
library(glmnet)

set.A = data.frame(matrix(runif(500),ncol=10))
set.A$Apps = rnorm(50)

X.A = model.matrix(Apps ~.,data=set.A)[,-1]
lasso.A.CV = cv.glmnet(X.A, set.A$Apps)

set.B = data.frame(matrix(runif(500),ncol=10))
set.B$Apps = rnorm(50)

X.b = model.matrix(Apps ~.,data=set.B)[,-1]
mse.lasso.cv = mean((set.B$Apps - 
predict(lasso.A.CV, X.b, s = "lambda.1se") ^2))
```